# Should a TRACE request contain a message body or not?

Tags: rest, http, hateoas

[HTTPbis section 7.8](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-16#section-7.8) describes the expectations of a TRACE request.

> A TRACE request MUST NOT include a message-body. [...] the response SHOULD have a Content-Type of "message/http" (see Section 10.3.1 of [Part1]) and contain a message-body that encloses a copy of the entire request message.

To me it seems to be contradicting itself indicating that there MUST NOT be a message-body, but that there should be a message-body enclosing the entire request -- How is this handled in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual spec is RFC 7231 (https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.4.3.8).

WRT question: one statement is about the request, the other is about the response.

Comment: Missed that technicality. Maybe I should revoke the question. Thanks.